# Using splice on collection of elements

Tags: javascript

I'm running this to get a collection of HTML form control elements

```
var elem = document.getElementById('display').elements;
```

and I'm able to run this to get a group of elements:

```
var elemgroup = Array.prototype.slice.call(elem,0, 3);
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to run a splice function which will delete and return elements. As far as I can tell splice only works on arrays. Is there a way to run splice on array-like objects?

Comment: Are you using the `display` id more than once?

Comment: Nope just once. I'm dynamically inserting and deleting input fields in a form with this id

Comment: What is `element`, it don't seem to exist, if you want to get children, simply  use `children`

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the form elements from the DOM? Or from the array?

Comment: There's a difference between removing items from a NodeCollection and removing them from the DOM. No array method is going to achieve the latter.

Comment: @Yukulélé OP said it's a form element. So `elements` is defined in [`HTMLFormElement.prototype.elements`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-elements).

Comment: I'm trying to remove it from the collection object returned by     `document.getElementById('display').elements;`

Comment: @JLRishe `Array.prototype.slice.call();` allows for you to work on array-like objects. As long as there is a length property it works. However `splice` doesn't seem to have this functionality unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Dallin Ok, but the question is _why_ do you want  to use splice on it? What are you trying to do? See: [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @JLRishe I'm extracting parts of HTML a tags, such as the href and alt attributes, and so I need to be able to work with groups of input fields. The user can modify the text and then convert it back to HTML.

Comment: @Dallin That still doesn't explain why you need `splice()`. `slice()`, `filter()`, or the approach I suggested below should work just as well.

Comment: @JLRishe I'm extracting parts of HTML anchor tags. An input field is generated containing different attributes such as `href` and `alt`. Thus there are groups of inputs that are related. I want to be able to do things like delete a group of related input tags as well as take each group and convert each group back into an HTML anchor tag. I'm using splice to split them into said groups. I'm not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: @Dallin And as I've already said, `slice` and `filter` will both allow you to separate them into groups without the problems that `splice` has. So you still haven't made clear why you need `splice`.

Comment: @JLRishe Splice = less code and I want to modify the array.

Comment: @Dallin Yes, it's quite clear that you want to modify the array. It's also quite clear that you _can't_ modify the array. What's not clear is _why_ you want to want to modify the array, and now you've given us a new mystery, which is in what way "splice = less code". Could you give us a concrete example (with code) of how you intend to use splice and how it is useful for the task at hand (you still have yet to explain this)? Perhaps you have some insight to share that would be beneficial to others. Or perhaps this is just an [XY problem](http://bit.ly/1BAmifZ).

Comment: @JLRishe I guess I should ask you nicely: dear sir, why should I create new, transformed arrays instead of modifying ones? You say the former approach is better, BUT WHY? Thank you.

Comment: @JLRishe also, I'm using the approach from the accepted answer. I'm not directly modifying the collection because I can't, like you said. It's three lines of code for me to copy it to an array and use splice to modify said array. I'm anxiously waiting for you answer to the above question.

Comment: @Dallin You have described _what_ you want to do in a rather nonspecific manner, but you have yet to explain _why_ you need splice for it or what benefit splice would provide here over other approaches (aside from some questionable claim of "less code"). This is the epitome of an XY question. And though you have repeatedly dodged the crux of my questions, I'll be happy to indulge you: there are huge benefits to using immutability and minimizing side effects in your code. It makes the code easier to reason about and consequently helps to reduce bugs.

Comment: @Dallin This is one of the fundamental tenets of [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). The rest of the programming world is waking up to these benefits and this is why side effect-free methods like `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, and `reduceRight` have been recently added to ES5, and why LINQ has been added to .NET. Using `splice` forces you to chase a moving target as your array gradually shrinks and you still have to access its parts by numerical index. That sounds like madness to me. `splice()` has its uses, sure, but I'm not sure this is one of them.

Comment: @JLRishe Now that you explained this, I have more knowledge and can base my decisions on more than just which has less code.

Comment: I know I'm soo stupid for thinking that splice has less code. I get it.

Comment: @Dallin I'm always willing to explain my viewpoints. All you had to do is ask. In general, you should strive to convey (with words and with code) what you are ultimately trying to accomplish rather than fixating on how you think you want to accomplish it and on solving secondary problems that arise as a result. That will allow the people answering your questions to propose solutions to the actual problem rather than an incidental one. Sometimes this will confirm that your original assumptions were correct, but often it will lead to a better solution that you would not have originally imagined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `elements` property of forms is an `HTMLFormControlsCollection`, which is a "live" collection, and thus read-only.  You can copy it to an array first if you want to modify it:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('display').elements;
var elemgroup = Array.prototype.slice.call(elem);
elemgroup.splice(0, 1); // or whatever changes you want to make
```

Answer (score 1):

As phari has pointed out, the collection is read-only. If you want a way to omit a certain range of items from any array-like object (similar to `splice()` but without modifying the original collection), you can do the following.

In general, it's a good practice to use operations that create new, transformed arrays, rather than modifying existing ones. IMHO you should not be using `splice()` all that much.

```js
function omit(items, start, count) {
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(items, function(e, i) {
    return i < start || i >= start + count;
  });
}

var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

snippet.log(els.length);     // 7

var els2 = omit(els, 1, 3);

snippet.log(els2.length);    // 4
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could use `$.makeArray()` and hopefully it will then work as expected.

If not, perhaps take a look at the jQuery source code, particularly the functions "makeArray" and "isArraylike".

Sourcecode [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js).